# How do i remove the parse error in guards in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

i am trying a haskell code to find the bmi of a person and i am using Guards for that

```
pls guide me fort his code
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> String
bmiTell bmi
| bmi <= 18.5 = " You're underweight!"
| bmi <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal!"
| bmi <= 30.0 = "You're fat!"
| otherwise = “Something wrong!"
```

after execution it gives me an " parse error on input `|' "
plese show me some alternative

Comment: Indent them by at least one space

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is important in Haskell. You must indent your guards.

```
bmiTell :: (RealFloat a) => a -> String
bmiTell bmi
  | bmi <= 18.5 = " You're underweight!"
  | bmi <= 25.0 = "You're supposedly normal!"
  | bmi <= 30.0 = "You're fat!"
  | otherwise = “Something wrong!"
```